# Error when attempting knex seed:run after successful knex migrate:latest for remote database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm running the following error when attempting to run `knex seed:run` against my remote postgres database (not localhost): `Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`.

I am able to run `knex migrate:latest` successfully and can see that the tables are created on my postgres server, but when I try to seed I get that error. I've run the same migrations/seed file against my local configuration and it has worked without a problem, but when I attempt to seed my heroku postgres instance, it throws this error (I'm not running my local pg service when I'm seeding the new db, which is likely why it's throwing an error).

Any thoughts on why it is attempting to connect to localhost instead of the specified db? Sample of my file provided below:

```
var User = require("./models/User");
var Project = require("./models/Project");

exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  console.log(knex.client.config.connection); //This returns the correct db info.
  return knex('user').del()
    .then(function() {
      return knex('project').del()
    }).then(function() {
      return new User({id: 1, firstName: "James", lastName: "Lee", phone: "123-456-2000", email: "test@test.com"}).save(null, {method: "insert"});
    }).then(function() {
      return new Project({id: 1, name: "Test"}).save(null, {method: "insert"});
    })
};
```

Comment: hi, can you sample your kexfile.js, one or two migrations and a few seeds? I'm just guessing, but maybe the seed might not be returning a promise or builder, maybe it's getting the wrong profile due to a bug... provide more info if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added some code to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have occurred due to how I was setting up the migrations / seeds. The configurations were actually pulling from two different places, one which had the correct SSL settings in place, the other without (seed file). Adding the correct settings in both places seemed to resolve the issue.